# PHPExcel, If $value = $value then skip?

Tags: php, html, arrays, excel, phpexcel

I'm trying to read a xlsx file using PHPExcel, however I got a problem trying to generate a navbar using column 1 values. Since Most of my column contains same type of value `e.g. T-Shirt, T-Shirt... Cap, Cap, Cap.. Hoodies, Hoodies...`
I got a problem filtering out the same value, does someone has any idea how to skip the same value as previous one?

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
for ($column = 2; $column <= $highestRow; ++$column) {
    $cat = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $column)->getValue();
    if ($cat == $cat) { 
        continue; 
    } else { 
        echo '<li><a href="'.$cat.'">'.$cat.'</a></li>'; 
    } 
}
?>
```

> Would be great if it works under `<li><a href=""></a></li>` for my navbar

Comment: `$cat == $cat` is always going to be true, so you'll continue EVERY record... you need `$prev = $cat` and test `if ($cat == $prev)`

Comment: Build an array if the values, then use array_unique(), and then build your navbar from that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
//Get the value of $column -1 aka the previous column.
$previousColumn = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $column - 1)->getValue();
$cat = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $column)->getValue();

if ($cat == $previousColumn) { 
    continue; 
} else { 
    echo '<li><a href="'.$cat.'">'.$cat.'</a></li>'; 
}
```

Comment: Life saver! Your code works :) 
> I will come back to make as useful when I got enough reputations. Cheers!